# Javascript loop continue,or break to display?

Tags: javascript

Javascript loop continue,or break to display?

This is my code use for show or hide some data in `table`

```
if (type=='SHOW') {
  for(var i = 0; i<list_tr.length; i++) {
             document.getElementById(list_tr[i]).style.display = '';
  }
else if (type=='SHOW_EXCEPT'){
  document.getElementById(list_tr[0]).style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById(list_tr[1]).style.display = '';
    for(var i = 2; i<list_tr.length; i++) { 
        document.getElementById(list_tr[i]).style.display = 'none';
     }
}else{
    for(var i = 0; i<list_tr.length; i++) { 
        document.getElementById(list_tr[i]).style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

In `else` case:

I want to hidden all but show `list_tr[2]` if`type=='SHOW_EXCEPT'`

How can I do in this case?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (type=='SHOW') 
{   
  for(var i = 0; i<list_tr.length; i++) 
    {              
      document.getElementById(list_tr[i]).style.display = '';   
    }  
}
else
{     
  for(var i = 0; i<list_tr.length; i++) 
  {
    if (i==2||type=='SHOW_EXCEPT')
      document.getElementById(list_tr[i]).style.display = '';
    else   
      document.getElementById(list_tr[i]).style.display = 'none';
  } 
}
```

That should do the trick if I have understood the question correctly

Comment: Use `.style.display = 'block'` instead of `.style.display = ''`.

Comment: Yes,I updated question,But if is there good ways by using break,continue,

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the question correctly, but it looks like you need `else if`:

```
if (type == 'SHOW') {
  // Do something
} else if (type == 'SHOW_EXCEPT') {
  // Do something else
} else {
  // Do something different
}
```

Comment: yes,I have tried,please look my update question,there are good ways with break,continue..